# How to sync Pidgin with gtalk notifications?

Tags: pidgin, google-talk

When someone sends me a message through gtalk, I receive the message in Pidgin and on my phone. When I reply to the message in Pidgin, the reply gets sent but my phone keeps blinking a notification light to tell me that there's a new message. A similar thing happens in gmail. This doesn't seem to be a problem for Facebook messages through Pidgin.

I know I can turn the phone notifications off, but they're useful when I'm not on the computer. Is there a way for pidgin to mark the message as read and stop the notifications?